# Monotonicity of the difference in expectation of functions of stochastically ordered variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose that C and D are independent random variables defined on the positive domain such that
$C\geq_{st} D$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ be a smoothly differentiable function. What condition on $f$ ensures that $\mathbf{E}[f(x+C)-f((x+D)]$ is decreasing in x, for $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$? In other words, what condition on $f$ is needed to ensure that this expectation is decreasing (or increasing) in $x$? Is it sufficient to have $f$ be increasing (decreasing) itself? I can show that $\mathbf{E}[f(C)]\geq\mathbf{E}[f(D)]$ when $f$ is increasing, but I don't know how to figure out the monotonicity of $\mathbf{E}[f(x+C)-f((x+D)]$.
Thank you.